# How does one list the packages in a .deb file?

Tags: debian, package-management, dpkg

```
sudo dpkg --install some_stuff_all.deb
```

Install the packages in the file `some_stuff_all.deb`.

```
sudo dpkg --remove some_stuff_all.deb
```

Displays the message:

```
dpkg: error: you must specify packages by their own names, not by quoting the names of the files they come in
...
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;
```

Then this lists the individual files:

```
dpkg-deb  --contents  some_stuff_all.deb
```

How does one list the packages in a `.deb` file?

Comment: Is `my_stuff_all.deb` a deb of debs? Your question seems to imply that the `my_stuff_all.deb` contains other .deb packages. Is that what you mean? Also, it looks like your last section (`dpkg-deb  --contents  my_stuff_all.deb`) answers your question. Could you [edit] and clarify what you're asking here?

Comment: Your question is unclear, but `sudo dpkg --remove my_stuff_all.deb` doesn't work because you need to specify the package, not the actual deb file. Also, you probably want to use `apt-get` to remove that package. `apt-get remove pkgname`, or `apt-get purge pkgname`.

Comment: So, if you do not know if the file has been renamed how do you determine the name of the enclosed  package?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To get information about a package file:

```
dpkg -I some_stuff_all.deb
```

This gives you all available information about the file, including Package:, Version:, Depends:, Description:, etc.

See `dpkg --help` for a summary of options, and `man dpkg` for details.  Note that `-I` is actually a `dpkg-deb` option, but `dpkg` runs `dpkg-deb` for you when you give it `dpkg-deb` options.  See `dpkg-deb --help` and `man dpkg-deb` too.

Answer (score 10):

There is only one package in a `.deb` file.

If a package file is named `example_1.234.deb`, then the package is named `example`. *(At least it usually is. Theoretically someone could rename the file.)*

If you want to remove a package using dpkg, you have to use

`dpkg --remove example` and not `dpkg --remove example_1.234.deb`

because you want to remove the installed package, not the package file.

Comment: Is there some requirement or convention as to what the delimiter(s) is/are between the package name and the other junk in the file name?

Comment: @C.W.HolemanII In all truth you can have a Debian file named `iamthenight.deb` and it will work.  The usual way (Debian compliant mostly) is `package-name_version-debianrevision_architecture.deb`, i.e. `nginx-full_1.94-1_amd64.deb` for the `nginx-full` binary package, upstream version `1.9.4`, first Debian package version, for the `amd64` architecture.

Comment: You have to be careful here.  There's a package named [`gcc-4.9`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/gcc-4.9) and you don't want to accidentally grab [`gcc`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/gcc) (that's a dummy package which doesn't actually do anything by itself, so uninstalling it accomplishes little).

Comment: The `gcc` packages does do something - it Depends on specific (usually the latest) versions of both `cpp` and `gcc-x.xx` packages, and Suggests: several other packages relevant to compiling software.  That's one of the purpose of 'dummy' packages, to make it easy to install a whole suite of related packages just by apt-get installing the dummy.  Also for transitioning purposes when a package is renamed.  The `gcc` package is an example of both purposes in one pkg as debian supports multiple versions of gcc installed simultaneously by having `gcc-4.1`, `gcc-4.3`, ... `gcc-4.9` packages.

Comment: The convention used by Debian derivative Ubuntu is that the `example` package will have a filename like `example_123.45.deb`.  This allows for something like `example-9.99_123.45.deb` in which the package name is `example-9.99`.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your package is named `foo.deb`, you can get extract the actual name of the package (as well as all the other fields listed in the output of `dpkg-deb -I foo.deb`) using `dpkg-deb` with the `-f` option:

```
dpkg-deb -f foo.deb Package
```

- `-f foo.deb Package`: extracts the `Package` field from the `foo.deb` package;

```
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp % ls -l
totale 46316
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 47425034 ott  5 05:55 foo.deb
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp % dpkg-deb -f foo.deb Package                      
google-chrome-stable
```

Expanding this, you can remove the package in question directly by using a command substitution running `dpkg-deb -f foo.deb Package` inside a `dpkg -r` command:

```
sudo dpkg -r $(dpkg-deb -f foo.deb Package)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not on a Debian-based system and don't have access to the `dpkg`... tools, you can still extract the information as `deb` files use open formats. They are essentially `ar` archives that contain a couple of compressed `tar` archives, one of them being `control.tar` which contains among other things a `control` file with all the metadata about the package (what `dpkg -I` returns (itself calling `dpkg-deb -I` to get the info)).

The `control.tar` can be currently compressed with either `gzip` or `xz`.

libarchive's `bsdtar` supports all those archive formats (`ar`, `tar.gz`, `tar.xz`), so you can do:

```
bsdtar xOf file.deb 'control.tar*' |
  bsdtar xOf - ./control |
  grep -Pom1 '^Package: \K.*'
```

The first `bsdtar` extracting the `control.tar` file on stdout to feed to the second `bsdtar` which extracts the `./control` member. `grep` (here assuming GNU `grep`) extracts the package name.